# Multiple Dynamics CRM Organizations with Single Azure service bus

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azureservicebus

I was using a service bus with a Dynamics CRM account, so as required I've set up Service bus namespace and ACS in Azure and Service-endpoint in Dynamics CRM.

Now there is a scenario came where I need to use multiple Dynamics CRM organizations with single Azure Service bus. I tried changing Service identities in ACS the configuring Service Endpoints in each Organization but only one Organization works at a time. So need help here to make both Organization works with single service bus.

Is this possible to Connect multiple Dynamics CRM Orgs with single service bus?

Has anybody done this?

Comment: If you are sending the RemoteExecutionContext, you could filter your messages by the OrganizationId property. I'm currently trying to get a similar scenario up and running but I fail to retrieve messages from the Service Bus Queue inside a Azure Biztalk Service.

Comment: I'm using Two-way Listener, and the Service Endpoint created in Dynamics CRM is tightly coupled between an organization and Service bus' ACS. So need to find a way or work around to accomplish it